# Como fazer um Criteria Join para esta consulta

Tags: criteria

Ao pesquisar um pouco percebi que existem algumas formas de fazer um Join utilizando criteria.

Uma delas é utilizando um alias e outra usando  um root.

Como fazer a consulta abaixo em Criteria utilizando as 2 formas e qual das duas seria a melhor (melhor em relação a desempenho)?

```
Select c.id from entidade c inner join entidade2 e where c.id=e.idC;
```

Alguém conhece algum site com uma bela documentação a respeito de Criterias e Joins?

Conheço uma forma de fazer mas retorna a entidade inteira e não é bem assim que  eu quero pois quero apenas o id da  entidade.

```
   Criteria c = session.createCriteria(Entidade.class, "C");
     c.createAlias("C.entidades1", "e");
     c.add(Restrictions.eq("c.id", "e.idC"));
     c.list();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se a criteria que vc apresentou está retornando a entidade que vc quer, basta fazer o setProjection:

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(Entidade.class, "C");
     c.createAlias("C.entidades1", "e");
     c.add(Restrictions.eq("c.id", "e.idC"));
     c.setProjection(Projections.property("c.id"));
     c.list();
```

Com relação à documentação, esse site é muito bom: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/pt-BR/html/querycriteria.html